# sample size calculation for parallel superior rct?

Tags: sample-size

Any suggestion on calculating sample size for a superior RCT in R or SAS?
I have used the 'pwr' package which gives me a different result from the one I got from an online calculator (Sample size calculator (riskcalc.org)).

my parameters are
control- change in mean- 20+/- 5
treatment- change in mean- 15 +/- 5
drop out -20%
power-0.9

Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Comment: Your trial design is not sufficiently clear. You have two groups (control and treatment) and you are measuring the change from baseline? You assume that in the control group the change will be 20 +/-5 and in the treatment group 15 +/-5? Are positive changes a "good" or a "bad" outcome? What is your significance level, 0.05?